# convert dataframe to dictionary pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this below

```
|item_name|item_value|timestamp                   |idx|description|
+---------+----------+----------------------------+---+-----------+
|A        |0.25      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |unitA&     |
|B        |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |null       |
|C        |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |C&         |
|D        |0.45      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |unitD&     |
|A        |0.3       |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |unitA&     |
|B        |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |null       |
|C        |0.3       |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |C&         |
|D        |0.21      |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |unitD&         |
|A        |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|2  |unitA&         |
```

and I want to convert it to a dict in this structure

```
  {'unitA&': {0: 0.25,1: 0.3,2:0.54},
'C&': {0: 0.34, 1: 0.3},
'unitD& ': {0: 0.45,1: 0.21}}
```

How can I do this with Pyspark?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map_from_entries`,`collect_list`,`struct` inbuilt spark functions to get your required result.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(20,False)
#sampledata
#+---------+----------+----------------------------+---+-----------+
#|item_name|item_value|timestamp                   |idx|description|
#+---------+----------+----------------------------+---+-----------+
#|A        |0.25      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |unitA&     |
#|B        |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |null       |
#|C        |0.34      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |C&         |
#|D        |0.45      |2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|0  |unitD&     |
#|A        |0.3       |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |unitA&     |
#|B        |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |null       |
#|C        |0.3       |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |C&         |
#|D        |0.21      |2023-03-01T17:25:00.000+0000|1  |unitD&     |
#|A        |0.54      |2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|2  |unitA&     |
#+---------+----------+----------------------------+---+-----------+

df = df.filter(col("description").isNotNull()).groupBy("description").\
agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(col("idx"),col("item_value")))).alias("temp_desc")).\
groupBy(lit(1)).\
agg(map_from_entries(collect_list(struct(col("description"),col("temp_desc")))).alias("a")).\
select("a")

req_dict = str(df.collect()[0][0])
print(req_dict)
```

**`Result:`**

```
{'unitD&': {0: 0.45, 1: 0.21}, 'C&': {0: 0.34, 1: 0.3}, 'unitA&': {0: 0.25, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.54}}
```